# Mounting failed iPhone to recover the data, iPhone shows up in lsusb, no blk device assigned. How can we force mount it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, usb-drive, iphone

I'm trying to recover data from a failed iPhone. iPhone is recognized as a usb device, but not mounted or assigned a blk device which I can mount.

**DMESG output:**

```
[958098.380690] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[958098.529554] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1281, bcdDevice= 0.00
[958098.529563] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[958098.529568] usb 1-2: Product: Apple Mobile Device (Recovery Mode)
[958098.529573] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
```

**lsusb output:**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58f6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 05ac:1281 Apple, Inc. Apple Mobile Device [Recovery Mode]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsb device output**

```
/dev/disk/by-id ❯ lsusb -v -d 05ac:1281

Bus 001 Device 011: ID 05ac:1281 Apple, Inc. Apple Mobile Device [Recovery Mode]
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x05ac Apple, Inc.
  idProduct          0x1281 Apple Mobile Device [Recovery Mode]
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           2 
  iProduct                3 
  iSerial                 4 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0039
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          5 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass       254 Application Specific Interface
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Device Firmware Update
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol     81 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol     81 
      iInterface              6 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install some package:

```
sudo apt install ifuse libimobiledevice6 libimobiledevice-utils
```

Then:

```
idevicepair pair
ifuse /mnt
```

to unmount your device, use `ifuse -u /mnt`.

Debian : [iPhone](https://wiki.debian.org/iPhone#endConfigTwo)

dedoimedo:

- [How to access iPhone (6s) with iOS 11 in Linux](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6s-ios-11.html)
- [How to access and mount iPhone 6 in Linux - Tutorial](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Since this iPhone is in recovery mode, its not getting paired.

 ~ ❯ idevicepair pair
No device found, is it plugged in?

 ~  1 ❯

Comment: @skg-net Install ` usbmuxd` then run `usbmuxd -f -v ` as described in dedoimedo tuto.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, I tried those earlier itself, its the same error. idevicepair is not able to pair when the iPhone is on DFU/Recovery Mode

Comment: @skg-net Maybe you need to restore it through iTunes (Playonlinux , wine or installing windows on virtualbox + Extension Pack)

Comment: Thanks, I would like to recover it, restoring it will wipe out the data.  I already tried with iTunes, upgrade fails, only choice provided is to restore.